# Many to Many SQL Query for selecting all Images Tagged with certain words

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have 2 Tables in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE "images" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    "relative_url" varchar(500) NOT NULL)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "tags" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL)
```

To establish many to many relationship between images and tags I have another table as:

```
CREATE TABLE "tags_image_relations" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "tag_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "tags" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "image_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "images" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED)
```

Now I have to write a query like "**select relative_url of all images tagged with 'apple' and 'microsoft' and 'google'** "

What can the most optimized query for this?

Comment: This is relational division. [Various approaches are discussed here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Don't know which would be most performant in postgres

Comment: @jerrymouse. You should check various solutions in your db. Performance will be different depending on the solution chosen and the data distribution of the tables. (what precent of images are tagged 'apple', 'google', etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the working query I wrote:

```
SELECT i.id, i.relative_url, count(*) as number_of_tags_matched
FROM   images i
    join tags_image_relations ti on i.id = ti.image_id
    join tags t on t.id = ti.tag_id
    where t.name in ('google','microsoft','apple')
    group by i.id having count(i.id) <= 3
    order by count(i.id)
```

This query will first show the images matching all three tags, then the images matching at least 2 of the 3 tags, finally at least 1 tag.

Comment: tags table should be indexed on name,id for efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

You'd join `images` to `tags_image_relations`, then `tags_image_relations` to `tags`, then filter `WHERE` the `name` field is `IN` a list of tag names desired.  It's the simplest, most obvious, and cleanest?

Comment: This returns `Any` not `All`. To do `All` would require a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Comment: Exactly, That was the problem. I need images with all these tags. Infact, I need to order images matching all 3 tags, then at least 2 tags, then at least 1 tag. Thanks for your answers anyways @MartinSmith

Comment: @jerrymouse - Well for your need given in the comments (which is different from the question you asked) `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` would seem to be the only way.