# PlayFramework 2.x Ebean query match manytomany property from a collection

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a model object that looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "selections")
public class Selection extends Model {

    ....

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Market> markets;

    ....
}
```

Where Selection and Market both have `id` properties and `static Finder<Long, *> find()` methods.

And i'm trying to find all the `Selection` objects which contain a `Market` that's within a Set.

```
@Override @Transactional(readOnly = true) public List<Selection> findSelections(Set<Market> markets) {

    // Query?
    return Selection.find().where()...findList();
}
```

I know i can do something like:

```
return Selection.find().where().eq("markets.id", market.id).findList();
```

to find a single market object - but what about finding those objects from the Set? Without iterating over the Set?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Do you want to get one single market by id? Or by what?

Comment: I'm trying to find all the Selections which have a manytomany relationship with any of the Markets in the Set passed to the method.

Answer (score 4):

```
return Selection.find().where().in("markets",markets).findList();
```

Comment: Excellent - that works for finding selections which have ANY of the markets.

Comment: I'm wondering how i'd get the selections which have a relationship with ALL of the markets?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem, and after reading [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267609/mysql-join-query-for-multiple-tags-many-to-many-relationship-that-matches-al) and [the Ebean's Interface Query documentation](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidoc/6/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html) I came out with this:

```
// Prepare the OQL query string
String oql = "find selection " +
    "where markets.id in (:marketList) " +
    "group by id " +
    "having count(distinct markets.id) = :marketCount";

// Create the query
Query<Selection> query = Selection.find.setQuery(oql);

// Set the list of market IDs
List<Long> marketIds = Arrays.asList(1, 30, 9, 15, 6);

// Set query parameters (list of market IDs and how many they are)
query.setParameter("marketList", marketIds);
query.setParameter("marketCount", marketIds.size());

// Get the matching results
List<Selection> selections = query.findList();
```

I am using **Play 2.4.2** with **sbt-play-ebean** plugin version **2.0.0**, wich provides **avaje-ebeanorm** version **6.8.1**.

For some extra functionality you might be interested in reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752620/many-to-many-sql-query-for-selecting-all-images-tagged-with-certain-words).